# 'X' must be numeric error in Decorana/VEGAN function after subsetting in R

Tags: r, select, subset, vegan

I keep getting this error:Error in rowSums(veg) :

```
 'x' must be numeric
```

I subsetted from a large dataset a small portion and when I run the DCA ordination I keep getting the above mentioned error message. I checked, but I have no character data in de rows present.

```
install.packages("vegan")
library(vegan)

Dataveg2018A <- subset(DatasetMerg, Year == "2018" & Block == "A",
                                     select = 4:7)
ord1<-decorana(Dataveg2018A)
```

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

example data of subset (DatasetMerg)

```
        structure(list(Year = structure(c(3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Names = c("18A01", 
    "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", 
    "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", 
    "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", "18A20"), .Label = c("2001", 
    "2008", "2018"), class = "factor"), Block = structure(c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L), .Names = c("18A01", "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", 
    "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", 
    "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", 
    "18A20"), .Label = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", 
    "I", "J", "X"), class = "factor"), Plot = structure(1:20, .Names = c("18A01", 
    "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", 
    "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", 
    "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", "18A20"), .Label = c(" 1", 
    " 2", " 3", " 4", " 5", " 6", " 7", " 8", " 9", "10", "11", "12", 
    "13", "14", "15", "16", "17", "18", "19", "20", "21", "22", "23", 
    "24", "25", "26", "27", "28", "29", "30", "31", "32", "33", "34", 
    "35", "36", "37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45", 
    "46"), class = "factor"), Agrimonia.eupatoria = structure(c(3L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("18A01", "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", 
    "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", 
    "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", 
    "18A20"), .Label = c("0", "1", "2", "6"), class = "factor"), 
        Agrostis.capillaris = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("18A01", 
        "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", 
        "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", 
        "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", "18A20"), .Label = c("0", 
        "2", "3", "4", "6"), class = "factor"), Agrostis.gigantea = structure(c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 3L, 
        4L, 3L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("18A01", "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", 
        "18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", 
        "18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", 
        "18A19", "18A20"), .Label = c("0", "2", "3", "4", "6"), class = "factor"), 
        Agrostis.stolonifera = structure(c(5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("18A01", 
        "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", 
        "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", 
        "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", "18A20"), .Label = c("0", 
        "1", "18", "2", "3", "38", "4", "6", "68", "8"), class = "factor")), 
  .Names = c("Year", 
    "Block", "Plot", "Agrimonia.eupatoria", "Agrostis.capillaris", 
    "Agrostis.gigantea", "Agrostis.stolonifera"), row.names = c("18A01", 
    "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", 
    "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", 
    "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", "18A20"), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All** your variables are non-numeric (factors), both in the original `DatasetMerg` and its subset (`Dataveg2018A`). You can see this issuing command `str(DatasetMerg)` which gives all variables as factors (and same for its subset). You can also see this in your own display of the full `DatasetMerg`, where all species data are given as factors. Here is just the first of your species, for which you give the data as:

```
    Agrostis.capillaris = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Names = c("18A01", 
    "18A02", "18A03", "18A04", "18A05", "18A06", "18A07", "18A08", 
    "18A09", "18A10", "18A11", "18A12", "18A13", "18A14", "18A15", 
    "18A16", "18A17", "18A18", "18A19", "18A20"), .Label = c("0", 
    "2", "3", "4", "6"), class = "factor")
```

Please note the last definition `class = "factor"`. The values (all `1L`) give the index of your factor level, and these levels are given in `.Label`. So all your data are ones (`1L`) and these are displayed as `.Labels[1L] == c("0", "2", "3", "4", "6")[1L] == "0"` which is non-numeric (a character).

Comment: Thanks for the comprehensive explanation! Is there a way to make this dataset compatible with the decorana function? Convert the dataset to a numeric one? My base-data is numeric, but it is very large. I subsetted this dataset into a list with subsets (and apparently transformed it to characters) and want to use each individual subset for ordination, without making tons of objects.

Comment: See R FAQ https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#How-do-I-convert-factors-to-numeric_003f. To avoid doing this conversion manually for each species, you can use `sapply(Dataveg2018A, function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x)))`.